# Save using .putString and later use it as class

Tags: android, android-studio

sorry for this simple question but im new to this.
I have this code:

```
public void English (View view) {
        if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("selectedlanguage", "English");
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sharedPref.getString("selectedlanguage", null) + " is the default page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            English();
        }
        else English();
```

For later use I want to use the `editor.putString("selectedlanguage", "English");`"English" as class name.

Like this:

```
if (sharedPref.getString("selectedlanguage", null) != null) {
//use the "English" as class name so it will execute the class
}
```

Comment: You can use Class.forName("")

Comment: Is this the only way to achieve your aim? Why not `if (sharedPref.getString("selectedLanguage", "default_val").equals("English")) { new English(); }` ?

Comment: @ashish-agrawal can you give me an example please? I'm trying to do what you suggest but says class not found exception

Comment: Can you give an explanation as an answer please so I can try it out? @PPartisan

Comment: Is `English()` an 'Activity' class or "regular"?

Comment: Its regular @PPartisan

Comment: Ok, I've posted an answer that outlines how I'd tackle this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off your question and comments, I'm assuming you only want to create a class based off a value stored in `SharedPreferences`. I'm also assuming you want to create several "languages", and launch the appropriate class from the `SharedPreferences` value. For that I would use the [Factory pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm):

First, create a "language" `interface` that contains the common methods for all your language classes:

```
public interface Language {

    //Example
    void speak();

}
```

Second, have all your language classes implement this interface:

```
public class English implements Language {

    @Override
    public void speak() {
        Log.i("Tag", "English");
    }

}

public class Chinese implements Language {

    @Override
    public void speak() {
        Log.i("Tag", "Chinese");
    }

}
```

Third, create a Factory class that builds "language" classes:

```
public class LanguageFactory {

    public static final int LANGUAGE_ENGLISH = 100;
    public static final int LANGUAGE_CHINESE = 101;

    public Language getLanguage(int code) {

        Language language = null;

        switch (code) {
            case LANGUAGE_ENGLISH:
                language = new English();
                break;
            case LANGUAGE_CHINESE:
                language = new Chinese();
                break;
        }

        return language; 

    }

}
```

Now, whenever you save to shared preferences, use:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

editor.putInt("selectedlanguage", LanguageFactory.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH);
editor.commit();
```

And then, when you want to use the stored value:

```
int languageCode = sharedPref.getInt("selectedLanguage", -1);

LanguageFactory factory = new LanguageFactory();

Language language = factory.getLanguage(languageCode);
```

In this case, "language" will be "English", but it will change depending on the "code" you store to `SharedPreferences`. This is a very flexible system that will allow you to add new languages in the future, and as you use constants there is much less chance of errors caused by providing incorrect values.

Comment: Thank you verry much! @ppartisan

Answer (score 0):

Please see this

```
Class<?> c = null;
if(StringClassname != null) {
    try {
        c = Class.forName(StringClassname );
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said im new to this, couldnt figure it out, keeps returning null